# Deselect last selected option in multiple select with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiple-select

Well, i have a change handler to add values into an Array or remove values in order to have only the selected ones in there. But when the last element is selected i cannot remove it from the multiple select as the change event does not fire!! Anyone having the same problem?

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Post your sample code.

Comment: You should provide us your code and html, otherwise it will be impossible to help you

Comment: use jsfiddle so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing what I think you're doing, there is no reason `change` shouldn't fire:

```
<select id="list" multiple="yes">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>


var values = [];
$('#list').change(function(evt) {
    values.push($('#list option:selected').remove().val());
    console.log(values);
});
```

Thus, you must not be doing what I think you're doing.

Unless you have the last value selected, in which case you can't select it again. If you need to process clicks on selected options, then use the click handler, not the change handler.

Comment: It removing elements